# logstash trying to connect to redis server on mapped ipv6 address

Tags: java, redis, logstash

I've just started playing with [logstash](http://www.logstash.net/), and I'm having a problem getting a log shipper process to send events to a redis server on another host.

The `output` stanza of my logstash config file reads

```
output {
  redis { host => "11.22.33.44" data_type => "list" key => "logstash" }
}
```

However, when I run the logstash process, I get error messages containing

```
:exception=>#<SocketError: Network is unreachable>
```

A bit of `strace`ing reveals that it's failing here:

```
connect(13, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(6379), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:11.22.33.44", &sin6_addr) = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

i.e. it's trying to connect to the redis host on an ipv6-mapped ipv4 address.  The host doesn't have a native ipv6 address and the connection fails.

How can I either get the process to use `AF_INET` instead of `AF_INET6`, or somehow configure my host to work around the problem?

In case it's relevant, my java version is

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the configs you are using in logstash

Comment: There's not much more to my config than what I've posted... and the answer turned out to be nothing to do with logstash (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=560056): the `sysctl` setting `net.ipv6.bindv6only=1` breaks Java networking in Debian squeeze (and probably other platforms).

The setting only seems to matter to people who want to distinguish ipv6 and ipv4 connections.  I don't really care about this, so I did

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.bindv6only=0
```

started the logstash agent, and it worked!

The creator of logstash kindly told me afterwards that you can also add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the command line.